# Statistical method for finding homogeneous groups of curves

Tags: r, machine-learning, clustering, k-means, functional-data-analysis

I need to divide a set of 100 or more response curves into groups.
These curves are formed by backscattering intensity along a range of frequencies. Basically, each curve represents the intensity in dB of response along a continuous series of frequency values (from 36 to 45 kHz with step of about 0.015 kHz). Each target is represented by a response that has a curve shape, with peaks and troughs throughout the response range.
I would like to find a grouping method that takes into account the shape of the curves and is able to divide them into 2 to 4 groups that are internally homogeneous.
[image: conceptual steps of grouping]
I am trying to use a k-means clustering, but are there any (in R preferably) clustering methods that are based primarily on the shape of the signals? In other words, is there a method that is more suitable for grouping curvilinear trends of a signal? If it were possible to implement machine learning techniques would that be okay too.

Comment: A good keyword to search for would be "functional data". We have [a few questions tagged both "functional-data-analysis" and "clustering"](functional-data-analysis), not a lot, though.

Comment: Also, "profile comparison" suggests itself as relevant